# How to get System.IO.Stream from a String Object

Tags: c#, string

I have string object. I need to pass this data to another object of type XYZ. But this object of type XYZ is taking only System.IO.Stream. So how to convert the string data into a stream so that object of XYZ type can use this string data?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You'll have to pick a text encoding to use to translate the string into a byte array, then use a `MemoryStream` to call your function. For example:

```
using(System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(
     System.Text.Encoding.UTF16.GetBytes(yourString)))
{
    XYZ(ms);
}
```

You can alter `UTF16` to be whatever encoding you'd like to use to pass the string.

Comment: add missing right parenthesis in row 2. I could not edit, because edits need to change more than 6 characters...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the string's stream encoded in UTF8:

```
System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( "the string"));
```

Depending on what you really want to do, you might be better served using the StringReader  class. It's not an IO.Stream, but it makes for easy text-oriented reading of a string.

Answer (score 1):

This code loads formatted text (rtf) into RichTextBox

```
TextRange tr = new  TextRange(RichTextBox1.Document.ContentStart,RichTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);

string s = myStringData; //myStringData is a string in some format - rtf, xml, etc..
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(s);
tr.Load(ms, DataFormats.Rtf);
```